# Javascript function shown in Jquery dialog

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, dialog

I want a Jquery dialog box with a javascript function I have that displays a list of ingredients (the ingredients are coming from a database which is why I have it in a js function).  I have this as a button:

```
<div id="dialog">
    //WANT showKeyIngredients() to show up in here, the dialog box
</div>
<div id="confirm-dialog">
    <a href='#' class="buttonstyle2" onclick="showKeyIngredients();">
        Browse
    </a>
</div>
```

And this as my jQuery:

```
$(function () 
{
    $("#dialog").dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        bgiframe: true,
        autoOpen: false,
        resizable: false,
        minHeight: 250,
        width: 700,
        height: 250,
        modal: true
    });

    $("#confirm-dialog").click(function () 
    {
        $("#dialog").dialog("open");

    });
});
```

I apologize this is probably pretty messy as I am new to jQuery and have been just copying and pasting stuff altogether. I am not even sure if this is possible.  I have been researching everywhere and haven't found anything. All I want is my showKeyIngredient() function to show up in the dialog box. The onclick in the html doesn't show up in the dialog box at all.

http://jqueryui.com/dialog/

I like the dialog box here, but want my showKeyIngredients() function to show up in it. And have a button that pops up this dialog box.

Comment: The dialog is just another `div`. if you want to insert info into it, select the appropriate child element in the dialog div and append to that. You need to show the other code, e.g. `showKeyIngredients`, to get better answers.

Answer (score 0):

Very rough and ready answer, but is this the kind of thing you are looking for? :

```
$("#dialog").dialog();
$("#dialog").html('<div> Some element with showKeyIngredients returned stuff </di>')
```

More fleshed out:
http://jsfiddle.net/npj3xbk8/

You'd could replace the .html() text with what it is you are getting back from showKeyIngredients.
(also I removed all the dialog settings for simplicity, they can just be added back in though)

Answer (score 0):

Any thing that you want show in the body of the dialog, just put that into the paragraph(`<p></p>`) tags.

Try this:

```
<div id="confirm-dialog">
  <p>
    <a href='#' class="buttonstyle2" onclick="showKeyIngredients();">
        Browse
    </a>
  </p>
</div>
```

Or

```
<div id="dialog">
  <p>
    <a href='#' class="buttonstyle2" onclick="showKeyIngredients();">
        Browse
    </a>
  </p>
</div>
```

I have also used this dialog in my website at many places. And you need not to do anything extra.

Working [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AmanVirdi/pj7bcovg/).